# Nginx Mod_Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

Hello I'm trying to set mod_rewrite properly, I had no problem with lighttpd, but i wanted swap too nginx.

```
location /highscores {
    rewrite  ^/highscores  /?page=highscores last;
} 
location /highscores/ {
    rewrite  ^/highscores/(.*)/(.*)$  /?page=highscores&list=$1&page=$2 last;
}
```

Problem is that if you put  direction such as /highscores/ , with / at the end there is error 404, and if you try /highscores/example there is 404 as well, but /highscores/example/ is working fine, does anynone could solve this?

I coulnt find solution on google.

Config

```
server {
        listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/include.d/all-common;
    include /etc/nginx/include.d/example.com;
}
```

all-common

```
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = /;
}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

example.com in include.d have the rest of code which i pasted on the top

Comment: Regexp `^/highscores/(.*)/(.*)$` does not match neither `/highscores/` nor `/highscores/example` so this rewrite does not apply. What rewrite do you expect?

Comment: Also, I'm curious, why do you want two `page` arguments?

Comment: I need just one but it is not working at all.

example.com/highscores shows 404
example.com/highscores/ shows 404
example.com/highscores/example is working but not at it should, it shows wrong parm list=$1

Comment: @Edited I added full config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did the same path, so I have pretty clear view how you feel. :)

Please fetch this project, and test your setup:
https://github.com/TeXXaS/nginx-configs

Key point is:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/testing-rewrite-error.log debug;
rewrite_log on;
```

That way you can see what is going on.

Nginx has something like internal redirect. So if you touch `index`, or `rewrite` - it means new url will be re-processed. If you look into that git repo - there is products solution, for partial rewrite. It means that example.com/products/ leads to one script, while example.com/product/the_product - goes to other location.